# wordpress - How to filter post by date,month and year

Tags: wordpress, filter

I create a WordPress post filter page. I want to filter posts by date, month and year. how can I do that?

sample..

````
          's' => (!empty($_REQUEST["search"])?$_REQUEST["search"]:''),
          'post_type' => 'post',
          'post_status' =>'publish',
          'cat' => 5,
          'posts_per_page' => 9,
          'paged' => 1,
          (!empty($_GET["monthnum"])?'monthnum' =>$_GET["monthnum"]:false),
          (!empty($_GET["year"]))?'year' => $_GET["year"]:false),
          'orderby' =>!empty($_GET["orderby"])?$_GET["orderby"]:'date'
        );```
````

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In this case you can user following argument to get posts:

```
$args= array(
  'post_type' => 'post',
  'post_status' =>'publish',
  'cat' => 5,
  'posts_per_page'=> 9,
  'paged' => 1,
  'orderby'=>'post_date'
);
```